# Eclipse Java Oxygen is not starting

Tags: java, eclipse

When i try to open

```
Eclipse Java Oxygen
```

it keeps giving me this error

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg
```

my jre is

```
 jre1.8.0_152
```

and i try to make workspace for minecraft mods

Comment: That's not an error. That's just a file name. What is the actual error?

Comment: Eclipse requires a jdk, not a jre.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the exact steps to solve could not open 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg' error:

1) Go to C:\Windows\System32
2) Search for Java in that folder
3) Remove java.exe, javaws.exe and javaw.exe from this folder
4) Open command prompt
5) Type Java it should work

Mind you, your error could be little different than mine depending upon whether your laptop is 32-bit or 64-bit. For example, if you are using 32-bit JVM then you can get something like Error: could not open 'C:\Java\jre7\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'.

Read more: https://www.java67.com/2015/10/error-could-not-open-java-jmv-cfg-lib-eclipse.html#ixzz6J0plEMyA